# robots.txt blocking specific files also block unnecessary URLs

Tags: url, web-crawlers, robots.txt, magento

I am using Magento for one of my site. In Magento there is a file `mage` (no extension file name is `mage` only) to block this file I write *robots.txt* as

```
# Files
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /mage
```

But this also block URLs start with `mage` like `magenta-color-item.html`.

How I write in robot to block `mage` only not URL start with `mage`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a dollar sign to the end of the string which means it will only match exactly that entry:

```
# Files
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /mage$
```

This will only block the mage file if it come straight after the root domain:

> www.example.com/mage

If there are any other preceding directories, you must add these o the entry. So to block the file located below:

```
www.example.com/somedirectory/mage
```

You would need to use:

```
# Files
    User-agent: * 
    Disallow: /somedirectory/mage$
```

Comment: It's worth adding that this is an extension to the robots exclusion protocol and my not be understood by all crawlers, though it is by those used for google, bing and yahoo which are the three of most value today. It can mean that some other crawlers would hit `/mage` because it doesn't begin with `/mage$` and they don't understand the `$` extension. If it's truly vital that `/mage` never be crawled then other mechanisms are needed (e.g. never having something else begin with `/mage`, or restricting access to that resource so bots just can't see it).

Comment: Another possibility is to disallow `/mage` and allow `/magenta-color-item.html` etc. While `Allow:` is also an extension, this approach is more conservative; those crawlers that understand that extension (which again includes the bigger search engines' crawlers, and `Allow` is probably more widely implemented than `$`) will hit `/magenta-color-item.html` and while those that don't know that extension won't, at least they are more reliably going to avoid `/mage`. This might be preferable.

Comment: thanks @JonHanna Your second comment suggest to disallow `/mage` and allow `/magenta-color-item.html` but in my case there are lots of URLs like `/magenta-color-item.html` with variation. In fact Google webmaster show almost 250 different URLs blocked, which are start with _mage_ and all these URLs are generated Automatically by Magento using logic based on user data. How to handle this scenario then?

Comment: I'd suggest just following Max's answer in that case. It's a good answer (I +1'd it anyway). I think the stuff I mentioned in the comments are worth considering sometimes too, but Max's remains good for many people (why I didn't add a different answer) and by the sounds of it, definitely the way to go for yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more proper to block `mage` via .htaccess rules? It is an executable that shouldn't be accessed through the web browser anyway, as in the command line only for module downloads and installs. With the robots.txt thing, you're only telling proper search engines to ignore it, it's still accessible for everyone else.